What is wrong with my stacking algorithm?
My algorithm
private void UpdateInventory()
{
    List<byte> indexes = new();
    for (int x = 0; x < Inventory.Count; x++)
    {
        if (!indexes.Contains(Inventory[x].ID))
        {
            indexes.Add(Inventory[x].ID);
            for (int i = x + 1; i < Inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (x != i && Inventory[x].ID == 
                    Inventory[i].ID && Inventory[x].amount < 99)
                {
                    if (Inventory[x].amount + Inventory[i].amount > 99)
                    {
                        Inventory[i].amount -= 99 - Inventory[x].amount;
                        Inventory[x].amount = 99;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Inventory[x].amount += Inventory[i].amount;
                        Inventory[i].amount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Inventory.RemoveAll(item => item.amount <= 0);
}

So I am trying to have the items check after other items in my inventory with the same ID and then it checks the amount of the current stack to make sure each stack maxes out at 99, then it adds the amount of the other stacks to the first stack and then removes the amount that was transferred, after that it checks through the inventory so that if any stack has 0 amount it gets removed, but for some reason it ends with every stack being 0.
I have tried having a loop where each stack checks through all except themselves, I have tried having a loop where each stack checks all stacks above themselves in the list, and then the image is my latest try but nothing works.

It would be better if you paste your code here instead of a screenshot

I would consider using LINQ to group items by ID, compute the total amount, and then redistribute the total over the stacks.

I think in the first loop you are checking each inventory against each other.
The only one you are skipping is
 x != i

but I believe you would rather only check those you haven't seen already anyway so for instance only start with the following entries in the first place:
for(var i = x + 1; i < Inventory.Count; i++)

so you perform only a "look ahead" and no "look behind" assuming that the cases for the previous items have already been handled by previous iterations of x.
Then, once you reach 99 you skip any other entries with the same index based on the indexes (btw correct plural would be indices). Which is also not correct.
You still want to check following entries using the same IDs as well
At the end as mentioned here your loop is skipping items at the end of the list as the list count shrinks while you iterate it and remove items from it.
You do however not need any Linq nor create a new list instance.
There is List<T>.RemoveAll which servers your purpose perfectly:
Inventory.RemoveAll(item => item.amount <= 0);

Overall I guess it should rather be something like
private void UpdateInventory()
{
    for (var x = 0; x < Inventory.Count; x++)
    {
        var current = Inventory[x];
        // only deal for entries that have items - the 0 you can already skip right away as it will be removed in the end
        // and 99 are already full
        if (current.amount > 0 && current.amount < 99)
        {
            // only check items after the current one
            for (var i = x + 1; i < Inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                var other = Inventory[i];

                if (other.ID == current.ID && other.amount > 0)
                {
                    if (current.amount + other.amount > 99)
                    {
                        other.amount -= 99 - current.amount;
                        current.amount = 99;
                        // in this case you can immediately exit the inner loop since your slot is already full!
                        break;
                    }

                    current.amount += other.amount;
                    other.amount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // remove all 0 entries
    Inventory.RemoveAll(item => item.amount <= 0);
}


Thank you! This helped alot, however, the wrong stacks are still ending up having 0 as amount

@HampusMCK also with the bottom section?

well the bottom section just checks the amount and then removes the ones that have 0 as amount, but it is the part where it sais that Inventory[x].amount += Inventory[i].amount; Inventory[i].amount = 0; ends with both x and i amount = 0

@HampusMCK I meant the bottom section of my answer I added ;)

nope, still ends with all stacks being 0

@HampusMCK bottom code seems to work for me, can you check again?

It works a lot better now however I found out that both stacks end as 0 only if the first stack has an original value of 1, if the value is 2 then the problem doesn't happen

@HampusMCK I can't reproduce this on my end tbh

Perhaps you sould try thinking about this problem in a differing fashion. Your code sample is kind of a hot mess, and I wouldn't want to be the coder who has to try to debug it when it breaks. (Ironically, just what you are asking people to do...)
Lets think about it like this: You have N items in a character's inventory, and you want to aggregate them when new items are added. Each item has a stack limit, and while you didn't explicitly say so, I am presuming that there is a fixed number of item stacks in a character inventory.
Rather than try to manage the stacks in memory, which seems like a royal PITA, why not rethink how you are storing the data:
public enum eItemType
{
    Arrow = 1,
    Bullet = 2,
    Scroll = 3,
    //etc
}

private Dictionary<eItemType,int> _Inventory = new();

With this, any additions or deletions are simple dictionary lookups, and its trivial to do math that would otherwise possibly span stacks. To determine how many stacks to render on the screen, you can just loop over the collection and render the dictionary value/99 and round up to get a stack count. The enum is just icing on the cake to make it simple to read logic checks in code:
if (_Inventory[eItemType.Arrow] > 1)
{
     // do stuff here
}

Don't conflate the problem of how many stacks to render with the problem of storing the data in memory. They are unconnected.

The loop in lines 144-150 removes items from the list while iterating over it, which is the reason that you have items remaining.
Let's look at simpler pseudo-code and run through it:
var list = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
  if (list[i] >= 0) {
    list.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}

now let's run the code -
i = 0
list = {1,2,3,4,5};
list[i] = 1 // >=0 , so it is removed
list = {2,3,4,5}
i = 1
list[i] = 3 // we skipped 2!!!!

Because you're iterating over the list while mutating it you're skipping items.
The simplest way to avoid this is, instead of removing items from the list, to create a new list with only the items you want to keep. You can use Linq's Where function, or do it explicitly.
In any case, it's good practice to split the logic into smaller chunks, and test each chunk separately with unit tests, in order to understand what goes wrong with your code.

Thanks for the suggestion, however, this doesn't change the problem with why the wrong stack ends up having 0 amount in the first loop
